# How can I change CSS className depending on length of array?

Tags: css, reactjs, conditional-operator, ternary, classname

I have a Gatsby project with a blog and I am adding a "related articles" section to a blog post. If the article the reader is reading has related articles with the same tag I want to display up to two related articles in cards with links to the articles.

I am iterating through an array that contains related articles using `.map` inside JSX. There are three possible outcomes:

1. There are no related articles and I will display nothing
2. There is one related article I will display with the CSS class of `styles.moreArticlesOne`
3. There are two related articles I will display with the CSS class of `styles.moreArticlesTwo`

I would like to change the CSS styles depending on whether there is one related article being mapped through in the array or if there are two related articles being mapped through.

How can I check the length of the array containing the related articles and add one CSS class if there is one article or add another CSS class if there are two articles?

```
{
  topTwoArticles.map((article, index) => {
    let articleNameForURL = article[1].split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase();
    articleNameForURL.split(",").join("");
    if (article[5] !== ghostIDOfThisArticle) {
      return (
        // I am trying to use a ternary to apply the CSS classes but it isn't working
        <Link
          to={`/blog/${articleNameForURL}`}
          className={
            topTwoArticles.length === 2
              ? styles.moreArticlesTwo
              : styles.moreArticlesOne
          }
        >
          <div
            className={styles.thumb + " " + styles.cover}
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${article[0]})` }}
          ></div>
          <div className={styles.info}>
            <p>{moment(article[4]).format("MM/DD/YYYY")}</p>
            <h3>{article[1]}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.button}>
            {index === 0 ? (
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon="arrow-alt-circle-left" />
            ) : (
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon="arrow-alt-circle-right" />
            )}
          </div>
          <span className={styles.overlay}></span>
        </Link>
      );
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see I try to use the ternary operator but to no avail. `className={topTwoArticles.length === 2 ? styles.moreArticlesTwo : styles.moreArticlesOne}` does not work.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems. A minute or two in a debugger or some console.log statements will probably tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Console.logging the length of the array shows the correct length, but my CSS classes aren't being applied, seems that the ternary isn't working. Do I need part of the ternary in ES6 backticks?

Comment: You're code seems to fine, however can you log `topTwoArticles.length === 2 ? styles.moreArticlesTwo: styles.moreArticlesOne` inside the map (before return for example)? Check the classname is fine there. Have you also put `styles.moreArticlesTwo` and the other one hard-code-ly to see whether it is applied fine on Link and showing okay in UI?